# Ambiguity error due to regular expression?

Tags: c#, emgucv

The error I am facing:

[image: Error i am facing]

I am developing a project related to EmguCV but when I add a Regular Expression for the checking of my text-box value it gave an error of ambiguity.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error into your question as text, and also post the code that produces that error. Other than that the error message seems to be very clear about what the problem is. **What is the question here**?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Capture` class is defined in both namespaces that you are importing, `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and `Emgu.CV`.
Specify which class you want to use exactly, and use its full name (e.g. `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture` or `Emgu.CV.Capture`) on line **28**

*PS: Next time, kindly don't use an image of the error and write down the text of it instead. And adding the code that is throwing the error is more useful.*